# Python string format width

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having problems replicating the format as shown in:

[image: desired output formatting]

what my results are:

[image: current output formatting]

I'm currently using:

```
print '{}.{:<20} {}.'.format(i,'sum so far:',sum)
```

I have tried left, right, and center alignment, but I just can't get the format that I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try first aligning the item number string:

```
tot = 0 
for i in xrange(1, 11):
    tot += i
    print '{:<20}{} {}.'.format(str(i) + '.',  'sum so far:', tot)
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert the entire header portion, including the `'.'`, to a string first, so you can calculate the width including it.

```
>>> '{:<20} sum so far: {}.'.format('{}.'.format(9), 123)
'9.                   sum so far: 123.'
>>> '{:<20} sum so far: {}.'.format('{}.'.format(10), 123)
'10.                  sum so far: 123.'
```